# Submultiplicative matrix norm equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis

is there any kind of matrices and any matrix norm with this Sub-multiplicative equivalence?

$\Vert A B \Vert =\Vert A \Vert.\Vert B \Vert$

Comment: For a full ring of $n \times n$ real or complex matrices, no. You would need $\| A\| =0$ when $A$ is nilpotent, but there are non-zero nilpotent matrices.

Comment: Well, I should have said for $n >1$ of course.

Comment: More generally, zero-divisors would have norm $0$.  In any algebra (with identity) of matrices that includes a matrix whose minimal polynomial is reducible, you'll have zero-divisors.

Comment: BTW this would be multiplicative.  Sub-multiplicative is $\|AB\| \le \|A\| \cdot \|B\|$ (which is often included in the definition of matrix norm).

Comment: If you are asking about "sub-multiplicativity", then yes, as all matrix norms induced by vector norms are sub-multiplicative.